# floatval($moneyString) returning 0

Tags: php, string-conversion

Code:

```
var_dump($prodCost);  
$prodCost = (float)$prodCost;  
var_dump($prodCost);
```

result:

> string(5) "$4.57"
>   float(0)

What am I doing wrong here? I am looking for the result to be float(4.57).

Comment: try stripping off the dollar sign.

Comment: Have you tried to remove the dolar sign $ ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The $-sign is not valid for numbers, PHP will break off after the first non-numeric char. Try this:

```
php > echo floatval(ltrim('$4.57', '$'));
4.57
```